# How to join Tables in Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

T1:

```
Emp_Id     Date        Sales
100        12/18/2020  145
101        12/18/2020  195
102        12/18/2020  126
100        12/19/2020  146
101        12/19/2020  100
102        12/19/2020  756
100        12/20/2020  125
101        12/20/2020  635
102        12/20/2020  123
```

T2:

```
Emp_Id     Date        Quantity
100        12/18/2020  25
101        12/18/2020  65
102        12/18/2020  45
100        12/16/2020  11
101        12/19/2020  12
102        12/19/2020  63
100        12/20/2020  72
101        12/20/2020  12
102        12/15/2020  13
```

Output:

```
Emp_Id     Date        Sales  Quantity
100        12/18/2020  145    25
101        12/18/2020  195    65
102        12/18/2020  126    45
100        12/19/2020  146    0
100        12/16/2020  0      11
101        12/19/2020  100    12
102        12/19/2020  756    63
100        12/20/2020  125    72
101        12/20/2020  635    12
102        12/20/2020  123    0
102        12/15/2020  0      13
```

I need to join T1 & T2 on Emp_Id and Date, so that one consolidated sales table gives the information of each emp_id sales and quantity numbers based on date.
Finally filling the blanks with zero in sales & quantity column.

Comment: When is your homework due in?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The solution is either `full outer join` or `union all`

Comment: I tried full outer join but it is creating nulls.

Comment: A full outer join seems the appropriate approach here and that you are getting nulls is a natural part of it. You can replace nulls with zero by applying `COALESCE(column, 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.emp_id, t2.emp_id) as emp_id,
       coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) as date,
       coalesce(t1.sales, 0) as sales,
       coalesce(t2.quantity, 0) as quantity
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id and
        t1.date = t2.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Desired result suggests that you don't want to "aggregate" missing values, but to display each row for itself. If that's so, see if something like this helps (the `ED` `WITH` factoring clause returns distinct combination of all `EMP_ID` + `DATUM` combinations):

```
 with ed as
   (select emp_id, datum from t1
    union
    select emp_id, datum from t2
   )
  select e.emp_id,
         e.datum,
         coalesce(a.sales, 0) sales,
         coalesce(b.quantity, 0) quantity
  from ed e left join t1 a on a.emp_id = e.emp_id and a.datum = e.datum
            left join t2 b on b.emp_id = e.emp_id and b.datum = e.datum;

    EMP_ID DATUM           SALES   QUANTITY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100 12/18/2020        145         25
       101 12/18/2020        195         65
       102 12/18/2020        126         45
       100 12/16/2020          0         11
       101 12/19/2020        100         12
       102 12/19/2020        756         63
       100 12/19/2020        146          0

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT t.EMP_Id, t.Date, t.Sales, t2.Quantity
FROM t1 as t
JOIN t2
ON t.EMP_Id = t2.EMP_Id;
```

Comment: Simple inner join won't give you the desired result as it skips unmatched rows.

Comment: ... plus you are building a cartesian product regarding the dates.